# Finding repositories using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to understand how to find repositories from sites like Github using Angular js.

What is the mechanism behind this? There are 4 functions in `MainController()`:

- `search` function which will accept `oNUserComplete` and `onError` as parameters. What will be defined in `onUsercomplete` function to display repositories on the output when typing initial characters in search box? And function to assign repositories will be there? On the basis that a loop will be there through table.

Comment: Please try to ask more precisely, e.g. using an example and telling us what you have tried so far. I do not understand what you want to do.

Comment: It's completely unclear, please explain/extend it if you wanna any answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to find repositories on GitHub you will have to use the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/)!

You should be able to make requests to the GitHub API via AngularJS's `$http` service.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer you should read the API docs to know everything about it. Especially the [search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/) is important for you.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/446qvx24/).

It should help you getting started. 
The following points need to be added:

- Error handling is not implemented but I have added some comments in the code where you have to add that code.
- Pagination for the results. Because at the moment everything will be displayed.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .factory('github', githubFactory)
 .controller('MainController', MainController);

function githubFactory($http) {
 var API_URL = 'https://api.github.com/search'+
     '/repositories?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=',
    //tetris+language:assembly&sort=stars&order=desc"
     factory = {
            result: {},
      findRepo: findRepo
    };
    
    return factory;
    
    function findRepo(searchTerm) {
     return $http.jsonp(API_URL +  searchTerm).then(onSuccess, onFail);
        
        function onSuccess(response) {
            factory.result = response.data;
            return response.data;
        }
        
        function onFail(response) {
         // handle fail here
            console.log(response);
            return {
                data: response.data || 'Request failed',
                status: response.status
            };
        }
    }
}

function MainController(github) {
 var vm = this;
    vm.searchResult = {};
    
    angular.extend(this,  {
     search: function(term) {
         github.findRepo(term || '').then(function(data) {
                // add error handler here because Github api will return a ressponse on fail (try with empty search, remove required from input to test) 
                vm.searchResult = data;
            }, function(error) {
                // triggered e.g. wrong url
             vm.searchResult = error;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as ctrl"  class="container-fluid">
    <form ng-submit="ctrl.search(ctrl.searchTerm)">
    <input ng-model="ctrl.searchTerm" placeholder="enter search term" required/>
    <button type="submit">search</button>
    </form>
    <div ng-if="ctrl.searchResult.data.total_count > 0">
        <p>found {{ctrl.searchResult.data.total_count}} entries.</p>
        <div class="list-item-group">
            <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.searchResult.data.items" class="list-group-item">
                <h2>full name of repo {{item.full_name}}</h2>
                <br/>
                <a ng-href="{{item.html_url}}" target="_blank">go to repo <strong> {{item.name}}</strong></a><br/>
                 <a ng-href="{{item.url}}" target="_blank">show json for repo <strong> {{item.name}}</strong></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2>The following is for debugging</h2>
    <pre ng-bind="ctrl.searchResult | json : 2">
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: For the automatic search of items after every letter you'll need a typeahead directive e.g. [ui.bootstrap typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). But please notice that you're quickly above the  `rateLimit` that limits requests with-in a specified time interval to 10 with-out API token and I think 30 with API token. So add a token to your app to have a better experience. Please have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/446qvx24/2/) for typeahead demo.